# Hypergeometric distribution with no number of defect items information

Tags: random-variable, hypergeometric-distribution

So I am looking at the problem here:

A hospital has received a shipment of 25 new X-ray machines. The hospital could lose its
license for housing X-ray machines if the machines are not properly calibrated at regular
intervals. The hospital uses the following acceptance sampling strategy. It randomly picks
n of the 25 machines and checks if the machines are properly calibrated. If it finds that one
or more of the n machines are not properly calibrated then it returns the entire shipment.
How large should n be if the hospital wants to return a shipment containing two or more
improperly calibrated machines with a probability of at least 95%?

I am thinking it is really saying that P(x = 1) + P(x = 0) = 0.05. If I wrote out the equations for hypergeometric, I should be able to solve for n. However, in order to use the hypergeometric distribution, I need to know N *population size*, n *sample size*, and D *defect items*. n is the one I need to find, N is 25, but I can't identify D. Is my approach correct? Thanks!

Comment: According to the question, $D$ seems to be at least 2. The required $n$ needs to be lower, if $D$ is higher. Hence, $2$ is the worst-case scenario requiring the most samples. And yes, the question can be solved using the hypergeometric distribution.